# How to make a clock in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I want to create a clock that tells the player the current game time out of the 20 minutes in a day. I couldn't figure out any commands that did this, so I made a Redstone clock that activates every minute. But now I don't know how to separate the output.
If anyone could give me a command that does this, or a way to separate the output, it would help a lot. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you specify the desired exact result of your device? How do you define game time? Numbers of ticks that have passed since the start? Sending a screenshot without elaboration doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the exact ingame time and show it somewhere, the `/time` and `/execute store` are your friend.

First we create a scoreboard to store the time and set some constants. Do the following in chat.

- `/scoreboard objectives add time dummy`
- `/scoreboard players set $TickToHour time 1000` (This is so we divide the result of `/time query daytime` to get current hour)
- You can set more constants just like the above one for more time units (like seconds or minutes), but I will leave you to that. Here is a template: `/scoreboard players set $<var name> time <amount>`

Then inside command blocks, pointing in a chain, in order, we will have:

- `execute store result score $time time run time query daytime` // this returns from 0 to 24000. 0 is sun rising, 6000 is sun above head, 12000 is sun setting.
- `execute store result score $hour time run time query daytime`
- `scoreboard players operation $hour time /= $TickToHour time` // this will devide it by 1000 returning 0->24. Basically time in hours.

Now if you want to show this value you can do in a bunch of different ways... But since you didn't specify how, I'll leave a idea/recomendation here:

```
/title @a actionbar {"score":{"name":"$time","objective":"time"},"color":"red"}
```

I don't particulary like constantly showing numbers above hotbar, but it works.

Comment: Thank you if I wanted to lets say change something like a /fill command at a certain time of the day using this command would there be any way of doing that?

Comment: Yes. `execute if scoreboard $time time matches <range> run <command>` . range works like `x..y` (inclusive) or just `x`